# Why does ipv6 default route disappear on Windows?

Tags: windows, ipv6

Initially when ipv6 is enabled everything works as expected:

```
Enable-NetAdapterBinding eth0 -ComponentID ms_tcpip6

Get-NetRoute -InterfaceAlias eth0 -AddressFamily IPv6

ifIndex DestinationPrefix                          NextHop RouteMetric ifMetric PolicyStore
------- -----------------                          ------- ----------- -------- -----------
7       ff00::/8                                   ::              256 25       ActiveStore
7       fe80::bf46:cae3:359d:9876/128              ::              256 25       ActiveStore
7       fe80::/64                                  ::              256 25       ActiveStore
7       XXXX:XXXX:XXX:XXXX:fc5f:4d7:7ba1:33ed/128  ::              256 25       ActiveStore
7       XXXX:XXXX:XXX:XXXX:967:4d50:721e:31b7/128  ::              256 25       ActiveStore
7       XXXX:XXXX:XXX:XXXX::/64                    ::              256 25       ActiveStore
7       ::/0                                       fe80::1         256 25       ActiveStore
```

fe80::1 is a link-local address of the router the windows client is connected to.

30 minutes or so later the default route magically disappears.

I can add back the default router manually

```
New-NetRoute ::/0 -InterfaceAlias eth0 -NextHop fe80::1 -PolicyStore ActiveStore
```

but it will disappear again after a short while.

Any idea why is this happening and how to fix it?

**P.S.** There are other Windows IPv6 clients attached to the same router and they don't have this problem. So, the problem is isolated to a single Windows Laptop.

**Answers to the questions.**

- *When the Windows client route disappears, is the router still working correctly?*

Yes

- *If yes, what is then its IPv6 address and what is the default route?*

The router WAN UGA: XXXX:XXXX:XXX:XXXX::1/64

The default route: next hop ULA

- *What is this router and does it lead to the ISP?*

OpenWrt 23.0.5 connected to ISP router LAN port

- *Which is the Windows version?*

Windows 11 Pro

- *Was the route originally added by hand or automatically?*

Automatically

- *Is this a local network or a datacenter?*

Local network

- *If you open Wireshark and filter for 'icmpv6', do you eventually see Router Advertisements?*

Yes, every 7-10 min on the Windows client side

Comment: Questions: When it disappears, is the router still working correctly? If yes, what is then its IPv6 address and what is the default route? What is this router and does it lead to the ISP? Which is the Windows version?

Comment: Was the route _originally_ added by hand or automatically? Is this a local network or a datacenter? If you open Wireshark and filter for 'icmpv6', do you eventually see Router Advertisements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that on Windows Client side both **Inbound** and **Outbound** firewall rules for **ICMPv6** under **Core Networking** and **File and Printer Sharing** groups are enabled.

The rules allow the flow of the following message types:

```
RS (Router Solicitation)
RA (Router Advertising)
NS (Neighbor Solicitation)
NA (Neighbor Advertising)
DHCPv6
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common configuration error on the router. The way it should work is:

- the client brings its network interface online
- the client sends a router solicitation (RS) message
- the router responds with a router advertisement (RA) message (which in your case has a lifetime of 30 minutes)
- the router keeps sending RA messages every couple of minutes to keep the lifetime current

In the case you describe the router is sending the RA in response to the RS message, but not regularly after that. This causes the route to time out and disappear after 30 minutes.

The solution is to fix the router configuration.